# Remove rows in a matrix in python if rows length is less without using pandas or numpy

Tags: python, matrix, rows

I wanted to remove rows in a matrix which has a length less than a certain length without using pandas or numpy or any other libraries.

I have written the following code which I think should remove the rows, but it's not happening. Please suggest a better solution.

```
mat = [[1,2,3],[4,6],[7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6]]

for x in mat:
    if len(x) < 5 :
        mat.remove(x)

print(mat)
```

Output :

```
[[4, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Expected Output :

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(mat).dropna(thresh=5).values`

Comment: @RafaelC I already said without pandas or numpy.

Comment: You tagged `numpy` and `pandas` for what reason, then?

Comment: @RafaelC Thanks for the answer bdw.

Comment: @RafaelC to clearly mention not to use them

Comment: This makes no sense at all.. anyway, `[sub for sub in mat if len(sub)>5]`